# Spring-Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE Unable to autowire RestTemplate for JUnit 5 test

Tags: spring-boot, autowired, junit5, spring-boot-test, spring-resttemplate

I have configured the necessary Beans in `@Configuration` class but have not been able to get the RestTemplate injected into my test class for testing.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public ProtobufHttpMessageConverter protobufHttpMessageConverter() {
        return new ProtobufHttpMessageConverter();
    }
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(ProtobufHttpMessageConverter converter) {
        RestTemplate http2Template = new RestTemplate(new OkHttp3ClientHttpRequestFactory());
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = http2Template.getMessageConverters();
        converters.add(converter);
        http2Template.setMessageConverters(converters);
        return http2Template;
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureWebClient(registerRestTemplate = true)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, classes = {RestTemplate.class, ProtobufHttpMessageConverter.class})
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class GRPCRestApiTest {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Test
    public void GetOneCourseUsingRestTemplate() throws IOException {
        assertNotNull(restTemplate, "autowired restTemplate is NULL!");
        ResponseEntity<Course> course = restTemplate.getForEntity(COURSE_URL, Course.class);
        assertResponse(course.toString());
        HttpHeaders headers = course.getHeaders();
    }
}
```

Any advice and insight is appreciated

Comment: `@ActiveProfiles("dev")`    seems a problem,   is "dev" profile active ?

Comment: Remove the `@ExtendWith`, already implied with `@SpringBootTest` and remove `classes` from the `@SpringBootTest` class. Also the template shouldn't be `null` but instead your test should blow up.

Comment: Yes "dev" is the default active profile defined in pom.xml. Adding `-Pdev` doesn't help.

Comment: Tried @M.Deinum suggestion but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The `classes` attribute of the annotation `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, classes = {RestTemplate.class, ProtobufHttpMessageConverter.class})` takes component classes to load the application context. You should not put in here anything except your main Spring Boot class or leave it empty.

Furthermore `@AutoConfigureWebClient(registerRestTemplate = true)` as you want to use the bean you configure inside your application (at least that's what I understood from your question).

So your test setup should look like the following:

```
// @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) can be omitted as it is already part of @SpringBootTest
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class GRPCRestApiTest {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void GetOneCourseUsingRestTemplate() throws IOException {
        assertNotNull(restTemplate, "autowired restTemplate is NULL!");
        ResponseEntity<Course> course = restTemplate.getForEntity(COURSE_URL, Course.class);
        assertResponse(course.toString());
        HttpHeaders headers = course.getHeaders();
    }
}
```

This should now start your whole Spring Boot context in `dev` profile and you should have access to all your beans you define inside your production code like `AppConfig`.

Comment: doesn't work means? Can you maybe add a full-stack trace to your question. Maybe the root cause is somewhere else

Comment: What stack trace? There is no crash. `assertNotNull(restTemplate, "autowired restTemplate is NULL!");` fails.

Comment: can you try to inject `TestRestTemplate`? If you want to access your application during the test this is auto-configured for your if you start the whole Spring context and the embedded servlet container

Comment: Which package to include for this missing symbol? Does it inject my existing `RestTemplate` bean?

Comment: Just tested. I only changed the `@Autowired` from `RestTemplate` to `TestRestTemplate`  but doesn't help. Still getting NULL.